# Indexing and slicing in pytorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, slice

I have a batch of 2d tensors of dimension  [B,n,n], and a tensor of coordinates of dimension [B,2].

```
a = torch.arange(48).reshape((3,4,4))
coords = torch.tensor([[0,1],[1,2],[1,3]],dtype=int)
```

The code that gives me the result i want is:

```
a[torch.arange(3),coords[:,0],coords[:,1]]
```

I just don't understand why i cannot just use the following as i thought ':' meant taking all indexes:

```
a[:,coords[:,0],coords[:,1]]
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the difference as *parallel indexing* vs *selecting by combinations*.

- In the former, you use an arrangement of the same length as your `dim=1` and `dim=2` tensor indexers to signify what to select on each batch element. If you detail the indexing happening with `a[torch.arange(3),coords[:,0],coords[:,1]]`, you are doing:

  ```
  >>> a[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3])
  tensor([ 1, 22, 39])
  ```

  Therefore, you will what I refer to as in *"parallel"*, which means taking first `a[0,0,1]`, then `a[1,1,2]`, and finally `a[2,1,3]`. This would correspond to individual values being selected and stacked:

  ```
  >>> torch.stack([a[0,0,1], a[1,1,2], a[2,1,3]])
  tensor([ 1, 22, 39])
  ```
- In the latter, you perform combinations since `:` refers to a "select all" on `dim=0`. Here again, if we detail the indexing, we have:

  - `a[:,0,1]` *ie.* `a[[0,1,2],0,1]`, yielding `tensor([ 1, 17, 33])`.
  - `a[:,1,2]` *ie.* `a[[0,1,2],1,2]`, yielding `tensor([ 6, 22, 38])`
  - `a[:,1,3]` *ie.* `a[[0,1,2],1,3]`, yielding `tensor([ 7, 23, 39])`.

  This is performed *column-wise* and not *batch-wise*. For all batch elements, we first take all `(0,1)`s, then all `(1,2)`s, and finally all `(1,3)`s. The corresponding operation can be performed with:

  ```
  torch.dstack([a[:,0,1], a[:,1,2], a[:,1,3]])
  tensor([[[ 1,  6,  7],
           [17, 22, 23],
           [33, 38, 39]]])
  ```